# What is a faster alternative to ToList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I posted [an article on my website](http://loganyoung.za.net/basic-crud-in-linq-to-sql/) that covers basic CRUD functionality in LINQ to SQL and to get a collection of rows and bind it to a gridview, I use the query's .ToList() method.

I've been told this is fairly slow (using at least 6 memory allocations). Unfortunately the guy who told me this isn't able to suggest a faster method and I can see that this could be quite costly if the query returns a lot of rows.

Here's my code for quick reference:

```
private void loadUsers()
{
    var users = (from u in we.users
                select u).ToList();

    gvItems.DataSource = users
    gvItems.DataBind();
}
```

I don't expect that any loss in performance would be tragic until the query returns rows numbering in the hundreds of thousands or millions, but can anyone suggest a more efficient alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the alternative is to drop the `.ToList()` and bind the GridView directly to the query which is `IEnumerable`. In your case directly to the table since the query is unnecessary.

```
gvItems.DataSource = we.users;
```

Comment: Actually that makes a load of sense :)